# Amazon links to item listings and promotions become broken in posts

Tags: bug, broken-link, amazon

In [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/909655/home-automation-controller) (specifically [this revision](https://superuser.com/revisions/909655/2)), there's a (working) link to

```
http://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Home-Improvement-Automation-Controllers/zgbs/hi/6478740011
```

which is replaced with

```
http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/6478740011
```

which redirects me to

```
http://www.amazon.com/dp/6478740011/?tag=stackoverfl08-20
```

which is a 404.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That only works for accessing an actual item, which is the only thing that would have an ASIN or ISBN number. The above is a link to a promotion page (or basically a search result page). The parser is stripping the number out and putting it into a URL that it doesn't belong in.

Comment: @animuson: ah! That's the problem here. I missed that the link was to a search, not an item.

Comment: @animuson I think I've encountered at least 5 broken Amazon links this year. Here is another example: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/761/undergraduate-level-math-books/1463#1463

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have been fixed. [Here's the link](http://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Home-Improvement-Automation-Controllers/zgbs/hi/6478740011) in the first line above: notice that it's now a direct link to Amazon, rather than rewritten through the SE ad domain. (As animuson noted, this bug only applied to item listing and promotion pages; links to individual items are still being rewritten to go through the domain, even though [I'd rather they not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334767/given-that-stack-exchange-no-longer-adds-its-referral-code-to-rewritten-amazon-l).)

Do note that past posts that use such links while this bug was ongoing will have to be re-edited to fix the links - as the rewriting happens at the time the post Markdown gets rendered into HTML, the prior cached HTML containing the bad link will still be served, so the post must be re-rendered to fix the links.